# Getting upload_max_filesize message during file upload

Tags: php, wordpress, upload-max-filesize

I am getting an error `"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize limit."` when trying to upload a file with wordpress. I found multiple eventual solutions but none of then worked with me

I tried to edit the .htaccess file by adding this lines

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

but after adding the lines, the website I get 500 Internal Server error when I try to access the website.

I tried to edit the php configuration from Cpanel. I augmented the upload_max_filesize 50M but still getting an error when trying to upload a 4M file.

I located and modified the php.ini file, restarted the server and still get the error.

Comment: Could you upload an info.php-File which will output your current PHP-Configuration?

Comment: Do you have access to change your PHP.ini file on the server?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case for you, but I know php_value does not work when using FastCGI,

Comment: I uploded a php.info file. I used it to locate the right php.ini file and than changed the value there. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to set following variables in .htaccess file-

```
php_value upload_max_filesize <INTEGER_VALUE_HERE> 
php_value post_max_size <INTEGER_VALUE_HERE>
php_value memory_limit <INTEGER_VALUE_HERE>
```

If you still gets the Internal server error, means you don't have permission to set/edit .htaccess file.In this case you need to contact your Hosting provider.